# Moving only the first file from any directory to current one

Tags: command-line, bash, files, mv

I have two directories which are called `1` and `POSCARS` and there are files in the `POSCARS` directory. I want to move only the first file from the `POSCARS` directory to `1` directory while I am in the `1` directory.

Thanks for advice

Comment: There are files in the POSCARS directory such as 3RD.POSCAR-001, 3RD.POSCAR-002, 3RD.POSCAR-003 etc.  and i want to move first one ( in this example 3RD.POSCAR-001) to 1 directory while i am in the 1 directory. Am i clear ?

Comment: Their is the new grammatical correct term for a non-specified gender.  Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move only the first file in a directory, to the current working directory, you can use `for`, because it loops over files in an ordered way. Replace `/path/to/` with the real path to your `POSCARS` directory, and test it first like this with `echo`:

```
for file in /path/to/POSCARS/* ; do echo mv -v -- "$file" . ; break ; done
```

This will find the first file in `POSCARS` and simulate moving it to the current working directory. If it shows what you want, then re-run the command without `echo` to actually move the file:

```
for file in /path/to/POSCARS/* ; do mv -v -- "$file" . ; break ; done
```

- `mv -v --` move the file and report the action, then do not accept further options
- `.` is the current working directory
- `break` means break the loop after the first iteration, so it will stop moving files after finding the first one

Comment: Short and sweet, nice! And it's also flexible for not just a specific file name. Good job on this answer! As I was typing this, I was about to recommend to explain `break` and `.`, but you just did. Always one step ahead!

Comment: thanks a lot @OwenHines :) I added even more explanation, was too hasty at first, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have appropriate permissions to move the files, in question.
assume I am in the directory, and I want to move some other directory here.

```
~/FirstDir$ mv POSCARS/ .
```

would be the general command. the dot, [.] say move it here.